# How the WordPress Array works Behind the scene?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

look at an Example of WordPress Array first and read till the End.

```
function register_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
     )
   );
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
```

I don't want Answer like its register your menu in Theme I know that I want to know what is idea behind how it can do it. I know we are using Built-in function in WordPress but that is simple developer created that for us to Reuse in our code but the Array how a simple Array can do many thing by providing KEY and Value. I am using it But i did not Know exactly How the Array doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the **register_nav_menus** function to understand how the array works "behind the scenes". You can view the code here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/

It basically merges the array into a global variable which is then used by two other functions to **unregister** and **get** the navigational menus. See where the global variable is referenced here:
http://phpcrossref.com/xref/wordpress/_variables/_wp_registered_nav_menus.html

Comment: Love your comment you help me a lot and very impressive